# Enable/Disable submit with checkbox MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I appreciate this has been asked before but I have tried various examples & cannot get this to work so advice would be appreciated.  Closest I have got is this code below which removes the disabled attribute as required but I want it to become disabled again if the tick is removed (I realize that's because there is no code to do this in my example but I have tried various other methods which I will show below, which won't work). Thanks

```
<div class="form-group" id="deleteCheck" type="checkbox">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.DeleteFlag)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.DeleteFlag)
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="DeleteSubmit" id="submitDelete" disabled>Submit</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="~/Home/Index" id="retrieve">Cancel</button>
```

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Notification.Id)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    }

    @section scripts
        {
        <script>                               

            $(function () {
                $('#deleteCheck').click(function () {                       
                    $('#submitDelete').removeAttr('disabled');                       
                });
            });                             


        </script>
```

Other examples:

```
    @section scripts
        {
        <script>                            

            var deletecheck = document.getElementById("submitDelete").disabled = true;
            var submitbtn = document.getElementById("deleteCheck");
            deletecheck.onchange = function () {
                submitbtn.enabled = !!this.checked;
            };


        </script>

    }
```

And

```
<div class="form-group" id="deleteCheck" type="checkbox">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.DeleteFlag)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.DeleteFlag)
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="DeleteSubmit" id="submitDelete">Submit</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="~/Home/Index" id="retrieve">Cancel</button>
```

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Notification.Id)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    }

    @section scripts
        {
        <script>                            

            $(function () {
                $('#deleteCheck').click(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#submitDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('#submitDelete').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                });
            });


        </script>

    }
```

Comment: Your element will be `#DeleteFlag`, not `#deleteCheck` - assuming `CheckboxFor` automatically adds an `id` attribute. If not you'll need to specify one yourself. Also you can simplify the code by using `$('#submitDelete').prop('disabled', this.checked)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, The element will actually be `id="Notification_DeleteFlag"` (so `$('#Notification_DeleteFlag').click(...`)

Comment: Good point - I missed the parent class.

Comment: Great, thanks, works perfectly!